# "apt-get install wget" installs wget with 000 permissions

Tags: apt, permissions, sudo, wget

I need to install `wget` and so I used `sudo apt-get install wget`, and it did, in fact, install it to `/usr/bin/wget`, but the permissions are all wrong (other lines for context):

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root   root         286 Jul  1  2014 wftopfa
----------  1 root   root      407696 Feb  7  2014 wget
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root   root       48112 Apr 10  2014 whatis
```

No permissions for any users on `wget`!

If I try `sudo wget`, it returns:

```
sudo: wget: command not found
```

If I try `sudo chmod 755 /usr/bin/wget`, it returns:

```
chmod: changing permissions of '/usr/bin/wget': Operation not permitted
```

What happened here and how can I fix it?

Comment: Please post the output of both `lsattr /usr/bin/wget` and `getfacl /usr/bin/wget`.

Comment: Thanks David.  My friend helped me fix it with "chattr".

Comment: Yes, that's what I was trying to get at with `lsattr`.

Answer (score 1):

My friend saw my message and helped me fix it by doing:

```
chattr -sia /usr/bin/wget
```

He suggested that I read `man chattr` to learn more about it.

That enabled me to do the `chmod`.

Comment: Just as an aside - you appear to be using the Feb. 7 released version of wget, there has been a security update so you may wish to get it..30 Oct 2014

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I did an ``apt-get update`` before that, so does that mean the version most people are installing is the old one or would I need to do something else to ensure it gets the latest version?